# Display a popup over a modal

Tags: jquery, html, css, modal-dialog, popup

I want to display a popup on a modal in my usecase. I am unable to hide or show any popup or any other div over a modal.The top and left positions are not being set for the popup.
I have tried z-index but it didn't work.

CSS:

```
<button id="button1">click</button>
<div class="modal" id="abc">
   <div class="content">
       <h1>Hi</h1>
       <div id="popupabc" hidden="hidden">
         <h1>Hello</h1>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
$(function(){

$("#button1).on('click',function(e){
   $("#abc").modal('show');
});

$(document).on('click',function(e){
   // getting mouse click positions left(x) and top(y).
   $("#popupabc").css({position:'absolute',left:x,top:y});
   $("#popupabc").show();
});

}
```

Comment: Please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem in your post .

Answer (score -1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
         function ShowPopup(title, body) {
             $("#MyPopup .modal-title").html(title);
             $("#MyPopup .modal-body").html(body);
             $("#MyPopup").modal("show");
         }
</script>
     <style>
      blink {
        animation: blinker 0.6s linear infinite;
        color: #1c87c9;
       }
      @keyframes blinker {  
        50% { opacity: 0; }
       }
       .blink-one {
         animation: blinker-one 1s linear infinite;
       }
       @keyframes blinker-one {  
         0% { opacity: 0; }
       }
       .blink-two {
         animation: blinker-two 1.4s linear infinite;
       }
       @keyframes blinker-two {  
         100% { opacity: 0; }
       }
    </style>

    <div id="MyPopup" class="modal fade" role="dialog" style="margin-top: 236px;margin-left: 245px;width:500px">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                    &times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">
                      <%--<img src="../../Images/banner.jpg" class=" img-responsive" style="width: 100%; height:450px">--%>
                    <blink>Here you can type any message which you want..!!</blink>
                </h4>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">
                    Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

--This one is added in aspx.cs code------
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Popup", "ShowPopup();", true);

Comment: Provide some explanation with your code to tell what your code is doing!

Comment: This one is added in .cs page